# Unable to make the Checkbox work with redux-form and react-semantic-ui

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, redux-form, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to use **redux-form** with **react-semantic-ui** and is having trouble with the **Checkbox** component. The **Checkbox** is not being checked. I've followed the example from the **redux-form** documentation, but no luck. Here's the Code snippet :

```
renderCheckBox = ({ input, label }) => {
  console.log(input.value);
  return (
    <Form.Field>
      <Checkbox
        label={label}
        checked={input.value ? true : false}
        onChange={input.onChange}
        />
    </Form.Field>
    );
};



<Field
  name="activated"
  label="Activate?"
  component={this.renderCheckBox}
/>
```

The output of `console.log(input.value)` is empty.

Answer (score 9):

Reusable redux form checkbox with semantic ui

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import { object } from 'prop-types';
import { Field } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { Checkbox as CheckboxUI } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const Checkbox = ({
  input: { value, onChange, ...input },
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...rest
}) => (
  <div>
    <CheckboxUI
      {...input}
      {...rest}
      defaultChecked={!!value}
      onChange={(e, data) => onChange(data.checked)}
      type="checkbox"
    />
    {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
  </div>
);

Checkbox.propTypes = {
  input: object.isRequired,
  meta: object.isRequired
};

Checkbox.defaultProps = {
  input: null,
  meta: null
};

export default props => <Field {...props} component={Checkbox} />;
```

How to use?

```jsx
import Checkbox from './Checkbox';

<form>
...
<Checkbox name="example" />
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know whether the checkbox is checked or not, you have to use

`onChange={(e, { checked }) => input.onChange(checked)}`

instead of

`onChange={input.onChange}`

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/KZBG8BQJM)

Comment: Hi, The example isn't working here. It just displays `Loading`.

Comment: Are you using IE or an obsolete web browser? You should be seeing something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/zfkRuAA.png)

Comment: I'm using latest version of Chrome. Now the form is showing too. I tried with your code too but the problem is same. I figured out that there's **hidden** class on the **input type="checkbox** and it has `z-index: -1`. I removed the `z-index` and now it's working as expected. But your's working without removing the **z-index** value.

Comment: that `z-index:1` is supposed to be there in order to allow the custom component to work properly. I don't think that messing with the `z-index` is a good solution 

Comment: But unfortunately the checkbox doesn't work unless I increase the **z-index** value to **3 or more**.